# Nailed, screwed, and hammered in one sentence

Tags: word-usage, slang

*"Can someone be so "screwed" because someone "nailed" an argument that made him "hammered"?*
Is my sentence correct? Can we use those three slangs in one sentence? I understand that these slangs have different meanings but can be used synonymously. But, can you give sample sentences using those slangs?

Comment: I would say that your first two are ok, but your use of *hammered* is not quite right.   I’m not sure what you actually intend to mean but an argument cannot make someone hammered.   But someone might think, “I’m gonna be so screwed when I walk in the door and get nailed by my parents for being hammered.”

Comment: Please note hammered normally means drunk. Nailed and screwed are additionaly both synonyms for fucked - in its literal meaning and as slang for being in trouble.

Comment: Hammered also means attacked or criticize forcefully and relentlessly. For example,  "He got hammered for an honest mistake. "

Comment: No such thing as *slangs*.

Comment: At the work party I got hammered, nailed the secretary, and now I'm screwed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *can* use all three slang (words) in one sentence; but no, your example isn't correct since it makes little sense. It literally reads: "Can someone be *'in such deep trouble'* (so screwed) because someone *'easily won'* (nailed) an argument that made him *'drunk'* (hammered). But how about: My boss *busted* (nailed) me at work for being *drunk* (hammered) so now I'm *in big trouble* (so screwed). Note that in 'nailed' an argument, the meaning is completely different than if my boss 'nailed' me.
The non-slang words: screwed, nailed and hammered, do indeed have more in common with each other, than their *slang* counterparts, which DO have different meanings in different contexts and so are *not* as likely to be able to be used synonymously. Slang is not exempt from language rules in general, -though it may get away with a little playfulness...

Comment: Hammered also means attacked or criticize forcefully and relentlessly. For example, "He got hammered for an honest mistake."

Comment: +1. Though I'd suggest that "nailed an argument" doesn't mean "easily won an argument"; rather it means "perfectly executed an argument".

Comment: Of course a "perfectly executed" argument wouldn't  make one "hammered" either. But if were to say that I "nailed it" in reference to a good test grade, for instance, couldn't it mean I "aced" it, by earning a high score? Not necessarily that I got a _perfect_ 100%, only that I scored very well (or better.) So doesn't "to nail an argument" not _have_ to be more than just a win (i.e. at least)?